# how to set the x axis in the origin order ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame `total_likes`

```
total_likes <- data.frame(month = c("June","July","August"),
                          likes =c(24413,28839,35060))
```

I want to plot month in x axis and likes in y axis. So far I have this code:

```
ggplot(total_likes, aes(x = month, y = likes , group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(size = 1.5, colour = "blue")
```

with this output was : 
[image]

Two questions axis questions:

1. Why is the x axis not in the order "June,July,August"? How can I fix it?
2. Is there a way to make a y axis start from zero not 24000?

Answer (score 1):

order your data

```
total_likes <- data_frame(month = ordered(c("June","July","August"), month.name), 
                          likes =c(24413,28839,35060))
```

Comment: it works! thank you
 Is there a way to make a y axis start from zero not 24000?

Comment: `+ ylim(0, max(total_likes$likes))`